# Is there a way to use quick explode on a plane object and make it look good?

Tags: animation, effects

I'd like to do something very simple, import an image as a plane and use the quick effect 'explode' but it doesn't really work well. I've tried extruding it and rotating it toward the camera to give the illusion of a plane, but the image is distorted. Is there a way to go about this either in BI or cycles? I've only tried in BI thus far. Subdividing also gives poor results. Thanks in advance.